# Consuming Kotlin Flows in Swift with SKIE

Tags: swift, kotlin, sequence, kotlin-multiplatform, skie

I'm playing around with Kotlin Multiplatform in a project where I share only the business logic data. In my `shared` lib I've implemented a use case class which provides a flow Repository States like this

```
class GetCatImagesForHomeScreenUseCase(private val repository: CatRepository) {

suspend operator fun invoke(limit: Int): Flow<RepositoryResult<List<CatImageDtoItem>>> =
    repository.getCatImages(limit = limit, imageSize = CatImageSize.MEDIUM
)
```

In my swift class I will consume the flow data and display it to the UI with the SKIE Plugin. So I've added the plugin to my `build.gradle.kts` file and wrote the swift code like that

```
import SwiftUI
import shared

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        CatImagesView(catImagesUrls: viewModel.cats)
            .onAppear { self.viewModel.startObserving() }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    @MainActor
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var cats: [CatImageDtoItem] = []
        
        func startObserving() {
            Task {
                let usecase = KotlinDependencies.shared.getCatImagesForHomeScreenUseCase()
                for catItem in usecase.invoke(limit: 50) {
                    self.cats.append(catItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CatImagesView: View {
    let catImagesUrls: [CatImageDtoItem]
    var body: some View {
         ScrollView {
             LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]) {
                 
             }
         }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the code, I'm getting this error message:

`For-in loop requires 'any Kotlinx_coroutines_coreFlow' to conform to 'Sequence'` in the for loop.`

Can somebody explain me what I'm missing here? I would love to use this SKIE plugin and I do not prefer to write some boilerplate wrapper for each flow.